# Visual studio 2022 is not auto-completing certain methods

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2022

I have recently downloaded visual studio 2022 for use in Unity and it was working correctly for a while, but today it has stopped auto-completing certain method names such as OnMouseButtonDown() and OnTriggerEnter2D(). Other methods such as Start() and Update() do work, but a majority of Unity specific methods are no longer auto completed. I've tried restarting visual studio code, restarting my computer and uninstalling and reinstalling visual studio code, but the error still persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Image of issue]

Comment: Looks like intelisense isn't working at all .. you have the UnityToolsForVisualStudio installed via the VisualStudio installer? And also the VisualStudio package via the Unity package manager?

Comment: Are you talking visual studio. Or visual studio code. They are not the same thing. You mention both.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can cause various of reasons, even some IDE bug (which Visual Studio 2022 has a large number) but there is pretty common solution for this one

Firstly you'll have to make sure, that your **Game development with Unity** workload is checked

So

1. Open **Visual Studio Installer** and click **Modify** button across your version of Visual Studio.
2. Click on a *Workloads* panel and make sure that **Game development with Unity** workload is checked as shown on the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqAzX.png)
3. Click **Modify** button at the bottom right corner.

Then you need to ensure, that desired version of Visual Studio is set as a External Script Editor inside Unity engine

1. Open Unity
2. Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools

And make sure that External Script Editor set as a current version of [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS8Rp.png)

Click on **Regenerate project files** button and **try to always open your scripts directly from Unity**

Restart Unity after those steps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I've checked in Unity and visual studio is definitely the external script editor. However, I was unable to find Visual Studio Installer for the recent version of Visual Studio, only the 2017 version. Is this something that should be on my computer or something I need to download seperately?

Comment: @BlackHammer66 perhaps we are confused as you say visual studio 2022 and later you refer to visual studio code. Which is a completely different product

Comment: @BlackHammer66 i think something went wrong with your cache files, 
try to take a look at this answer
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-installer-cant-find-existing-install/784940